# How could I dynamically call the function with parameters

Tags: python

Let's say I put the function calls into list,

```
['next_release()', 'last_release("com_disagg")']
```

Hope to get the equivalent results of following

How could I get it in Python

**iterate the array and dynamically call the function with params.**

```
next_release()
last_release("com_disagg")
```

**call head() method for each function**

```
next_release().head()
last_release("com_disagg").head()
```

**add print for each function**

```
print next_release().head()
print last_release("com_disagg").head()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = ['next_release()', 'last_release("com_disagg")']
class t(object):
    def head(self):
        print "inside head"
        return "head printed"

def next_release():
    print "nr"
    return t()
def last_release(var):
    print var
    return t()

for i in arr:
    eval(i)

for i in arr:
    print eval(i+".head()")

for i in arr:
    print eval(i).head()
```

Output:

```
nr
com_disagg
nr
inside head
head printed
com_disagg
inside head
head printed
nr
inside head
head printed
com_disagg
inside head
head printed
```

Comment: You are not calling head ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're storing a string representing a function. That's probably not what you want since it'll force you to use `eval` which is usually bad.

You could get away with a mapping if you have to do it with strings:

```
mapping = {
    'next_release()': next_release(),
    'last_release("com_disagg")': last_release("com_disagg")
}
```

And now you can get the result using the mapping (`mapping["next_release()"]` ...).

There are two better options using actual functions and not strings:

If you want the list to store the functions' **results** (after calling them):

```
functions_results = [next_release(), last_release("com_disagg")]
list_of_functions_heads = [x.head() for x in list_of_functions_results]
```

If you want the list to store a functions' **references** (notice I closed the function with arguments in a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) to create a parameter-less function:

```
functions_references = [next_release, lambda: last_release("com_disagg")]
list_of_functions_heads = [x().head() for x in list_of_functions_results]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use clsoure:

```
arr = ['next_release()', 'last_release("com_disagg")']  
def next_release():  
    def head():  
      return x;  

def last_release(var):  
    def head():  
     return y;  

for i in arr:
    print i.head()
```